# How to loop dates into a Proc Sql where statement

Tags: sql, date, macros, proc

I have hundreds of date macros that i need to utilise to create some criteria for a merge between two tables. I have include a small sample below to provide context of what i am trying to do.

Essentially i am trying to not have to write hundreds of lines of code for the merge criteria, and was hoping i could possible write this criteria within a macro?

````
%let month01 = 01jul2020;
%let month02 = 01aug2020;
%let date00 = 04jun2020;
%let date01 = 08jul2020;
%let date02 = 06aug2020;
%let date_end00 = 07jul2020;
%let date_end01 = 05aug2020;
%let date_end02 = 08sep2020;

proc sql;
    create table test_merge 
as select a.*,b.*

    from trial as a
 left join trial2 as b 
         on a.id=b.id 
and
    ((a.date1 = "01jun2020"d,  and b.date2 between "04jun2020"d, and "07jul2020"d) or
    (a.date1 = "01jul2020"d,  and b.date2 between " 08jul2020"d, and "05aug2020"d) or 
    (a.date1 = "01aug2020"d,  and b.date2 between "06aug2020"d, and "08sep2020"d));
quit;

proc sql;
create table test_merge as select 

a.*,
b.*

from trial as a 
left join trial2 as b 
on a.id=b.id 
and
((a.date1 = "month00."d,  and b.date2 between "date00."d, and "date01."d)
or
(a.date1 = "month01."d,  and b.date2 between "date01."d, and "date02."d)
or 
(a.date1 = "month02."d,  and b.date2 between "date02."d, and "date03."d)
quit;```
````

Comment: This seems solvable as a single sql statement. I'm not sure why you are going through all of this complication and potential looping (looping just has no place in an RDBMS except in the most extreme circumstances, which this isn't). Why not something like `SELECT * FROM trial LEFT OUTER JOIN trial2 on trial2.date2 BETWEEN trial1.date1 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH and trial.date1. INTERVAL '2' MONTH WHERE trial1.date1 BETWEEN "01jun2020"d AND "01aug2020"d;` (Not sure on the right syntax since you don't say what RDBMS you are using). Can you explain more about the overall problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by RDBMS, this is a proc SQL step within SAS. I'm not sure what the Interval part does in your code. I was just looking to see if there was a way where i could create a piece of code that would allow me to have the required criteria for multiple months without have to write out lines and lines of code.

Comment: `RDBMS`?? ... Relational DataBase Management System.

Comment: RDBMS would be SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, Postgres, Teradata, MariaDB, Snowflake, Azure, etc. Likely the best solution to your overarching problem is solved by utilizing the RDBMS that is processing your requests to do this in one shot instead of many over and over and over again.